# Unable to install VS2005 redist @W7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, redistributable

I am struggling with installing VS2005 64/x86 redistributable for W7 64bit:

During install it displays an error:

> Error 1935: An error occured during
>   the installation of assembly
>   'Microsoft.VC90.ATL, version
>   9.0.30729.1,publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b", processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'.
>   Please refer to Help and Support for
>   more information. HRESULT: 0x800736FD

Spent like 2 hours in google, no luck :-(
Any ideas?

Comment: What else is installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall windows.
It appeared it was so broken, that even windows repaid hanged....

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970652

This is covered in this microsoft article. reboot. remove registry keys. try again.

Comment: A bit more detail from the article linked would make this more useful.  Links can break.  Can you add some detail from the linked article?